# Asp.Net Core MVC pass string from Controller 1 to Controller 2 and use in View 2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Cannot work out how to simply pass a string from Controller 1 to Controller 2 and use in View 2. Can someone provide a simple example for me?

Comment: How is control being passed from one controller to the other in this case?  Can you provide an example of what you have and what you've tried?

Comment: Controller 1
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWorkTicket(int? id)
        {

            Complaints data = new Complaints()
            {
                UniqueId = Id
            };
            TempData["mydata"] = data;

            return RedirectToAction("Create","WorkTickets");
        }

Comment: //Controller 2
        // GET: WorkTickets/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Complaints data = TempData["mydata"] as Complaints;
            return View(data);
        }

Comment: //Controller 2 Create View
//WorkTickets Create
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label">ID</label>
        <input asp-for="Id" onclick="ZoomMap()" class="form-control" value=@TempData["mydata"] />
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

Comment: @Tricky035, based on your code ,I have give the right code sample for your reference in the following reply, if you have any other requirement, please let me know and give me your code.

Comment: Thank you @YongqingYu can you give me an example that passes a string rather than an object?

Comment: @Tricky035, I have updated my answer, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You said to pass a string from one controller to another, however, the
> code you provided in comment is passing an object of Complaints.

If you want to **pass an object by TempData**, you need to **convert object to json first** ,then put this json in the TempData, when you want to get the object, you need to get the TempData and **deserialize the json to object**.

```
 public class Complaints
    {
        public int? UniqueId { get; set; }
    }
```

Change your code as follow:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWorkTicket(int? id)
        {
            Complaints data = new Complaints() { UniqueId = id };
            TempData["mydata"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);// convert object to json
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "WorkTickets");
        }
```

/WorkTickets/Create

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Complaints data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Complaints>(TempData["mydata"].ToString());//convert json to object
            return View(data);
        }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model Complaints
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="UniqueId" class="control-label">ID</label>
    <input asp-for="UniqueId" onclick="ZoomMap()" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="UniqueId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Test result:

[image]

**Update**

To pass a string , you can use TempData directly, or pass from controller to view, you can refer to the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWorkTicket(int? id)
        { 
            TempData["MyString"] = "hello";
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "WorkTickets");
        }
   public IActionResult Create()
        { 
            var data = TempData["MyString"].ToString();
            return View((object)data);
        }
```

View:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<div class="form-group">
    <input  class="form-control" value="@Model" />@*first way*@
    <input  class="form-control" value="@TempData["MyString"].ToString()" />@*second way*@
</div>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @YongqingYu can you give me an example that passes a string rather than an object?

Comment: @Tricky035, I have updated my answer, you can refer to it.

Comment: I am trying to do it as you have above (@*second way*@) however I get this error the below error. I don't want to use @Model String if possible, as I have a WorkTickets model that I have to use

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.this[TKey].get returned null.

Comment: @Tricky035, I recommend you to edit your post and show us your current compelete code which cause this error ,otherwise I cannot find the key of this issue.

Comment: @Tricky035, I did reproduce your problem, If `TempData["mystring"]` in the view is null, then it will show the error your provided, please make sure that the name in your TempData is consistent, or you can confirm whether you can get the contents of TempData in the Create method by debugging the code?

Comment: Thank you for all your help  @YongqingYu. It was completely my error. My button click was skipping the CreateWorkTicket Action and therefore not getting or sending the string from the Request Controller to the WorkTickets controller - a really embarrassing oversight.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make the view a strongly type view and bind primitive values to input field like

```
@model Complaints

<div class="form-group"> <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label">ID</label> <input asp-for="Id" onclick="ZoomMap()" class="form-control" value=@Model.Value1 /> <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span> </div>
```